# Retrieving data from 2 python scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

This is the first script which get's data from a website:

```
import requests


def get_prices():
    name = "SeedifyFund"

    crypto_data = requests.get("https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/tokens").json()["data"]

    data = None
    for i in crypto_data:
        current = crypto_data[i]

        if current['name'] == name:
          data = {
              "PriceUSD": current["price"],
              "PriceBNB": current["price_BNB"],
          }

    return data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(get_prices())
```

The code above outputs the following: {'PriceUSD': '1.022239219137518991087869433174527', 'PriceBNB': '0.002452203037583603303073246037795846'}

I'm having issue an issue with the second script. I want it to use the data that it has collected above and print it in a telegram bot when the user types /price. The code for the second script:

```
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler
from tracker import get_prices


telegram_bot_token = "API TOKEN"

updater = Updater(token=telegram_bot_token, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher


def price(update, context):
    chat_id = update.effective_chat.id
    message = ""

    crypto_data = get_prices()
    for i in crypto_data:
        bnbprice = crypto_data[i]["pricebnb"]
        usdprice = crypto_data[i]["priceusd"]
        message += f"1 SFUND = \n${usdprice:,.2f} USD\n{bnbprice:.3f} BNB\n\n"

    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)


dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("price", price))
updater.start_polling()
```

When the user types /price in the telegram chat it give this error:

```
coin = crypto_data[i]["pricebnb"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and help me solve the issue. Many thanks

Comment: Have you got the capitalisation right? In the first script I see 'PriceBNB' and the second 'pricebnb'. Also why is the crypto_data in a loop? As it is a dict just doing bnbprice = crypto_data["PriceBnB"] should work

Comment: Ah ok. That fixed the issue. Thanks